# Display:flex and height in 'vh' changes height of footer

Tags: html, css

I found a curiousity about `display: flex` in combination with `height` set as `vh`. I want a layout with footer. But the footer is smaller than configured (not 200px high (red)). For demonstration purposes I added a media query: Run the code snipped, reduce the browser width, and you can see that the visual height of the footer increases (to 200px (green)).

I reproduced this with Opera, Firefox, Chrome, IE, and Edge. So I guess it is not a bug. But how can this behavior be explained?

```css
.header-body-footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

.body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
}

.footer {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

    .footer::after {
        content: " - height is not 200px!";
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .header-body-footer-container {
        height: auto;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: green;
    }

        .footer::after {
            content: " - height is 200px!";
        }
}
```

```html
    <div class="header-body-footer-container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="body">body</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Vikas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58110591/2484903) I found the explaination.

Background:

- [`min-height` overrules `height` and `max-height`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-height/)
- [`max-height` only overrides `height`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-height/)

So, since my `height` value was ignored (but Vikas's `min-height` worked), I concluded that there must be some implicit `max-height`. And indeed! It seems that the [default value of `flex-shrink` (which is 1)](https://cssreference.io/property/flex-shrink/) introduces this implicit `max-height` value.

To prevent `flex` from shrinking the size of my footer I need to set `flex-shrink: 0` on `.footer`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `height:200px;` to `min-height: 200px;` for **.footer**

```css
.header-body-footer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: calc(100vh - 30px);
}

.body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
}

.footer {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

    .footer::after {
        content: " - height is not 200px!";
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .header-body-footer-container {
        height: auto;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: green;
    }

        .footer::after {
            content: " - height is 200px!";
        }
}
```

```html
    <div class="header-body-footer-container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="body">body</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```